# use ClassA's enum in ClassB

Tags: c++, vector, parameters, enums

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to use classA's public enum in another class.  Any help would be appreciated.  thanks

```cpp
// proA.h
#pragma once

//#include "editEntity.h" // ***This was my problem***

class proA
{
public:
  enum myEnum
  {
    jnkA,
    jnkB,
    jnkC
  };
};
```

```cpp
// proB.h
#pragma once

#include "proA.h"
#include <vector>
//class bld_DeviceFilter;

class proB
{
private:
  std::vector<proA::myEnum> list_of_myEnums;
};
```

if I have 'class proA' uncommented I get the following error:

```
Error 7 error C2027: use of undefined type 'proA'
```

If I have '#include proA.h' I get the following error:

```
Error 11 error C2027: use of undefined type 'proA'
```

I read in another stack overflow page that you need to place 'enum' before proA::myEnum in order to use an enum as a type.  when I did as suggested:

```cpp
std::vector<enum proA::myEnum> list_of_myEnums;
```

I then got the following error:

```
Error 16 error C2011: proA : 'enum' type redefinition
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part

Comment: no, that was just a type in stack overflow question.  proA is not a namespace and myEnum is not static.

Comment: You lack semicolons at the end of your class definitions.

Comment: when hover over the std::vector<proA::myEnum> section, intellisense states that 'Error: incomplete type is not allowed' so I'll Look into this some

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe you have a cycle in your header inclusion or something...

Comment: Could you first #include "proA.h", move your #pragma once below and tell the result of compilation?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    enum m_enum
    {
        ENUM_1,
        ENUM_2,
        ENUM_3
    };
};
```

ClassB:

```
#include "ClassA.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class ClassB
{
    std::vector<ClassA::m_enum> m_vec;

public:
    ClassB()
    {
        ClassA::m_enum enum1;
        ClassA::m_enum enum2;
        ClassA::m_enum enum3;

        m_vec.push_back(enum1);
        m_vec.push_back(enum2);
        m_vec.push_back(enum3);

        std::cout << m_vec.size() << std::endl;
    }
};
```

main:

```
#include "ClassB.h"

int main()
{
    ClassB classB;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for a few things:
1- Is `#include <vector>` in you code?
2- Are both classes on the same project and are both marked to be compiled?

The enum does not need to be static, I made a quick test here and it work as you posted, excepet for the missing `#include <vector>`.

Comment: If anyone want to post an answer which suggests uncommenting out any unneeded #include statements from proA (and maybe why this caused build failure), I’ll go ahead and check that off as the correct answer.

Comment: The include statement in proA was "#include "proB.h", so it must have been circular logic causing the issue(?).

Comment: When the conversation turned to #include statements, I decided to commented out all #include statements within proA.  Thanks for the help in figuring out what was going wrong.

Comment: @Tanuki although it is not ansi C, it is fully suported and encouraged in Visual Studio to use it.

@Fractal have you tried the `#include <vector>` on ProB.h?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define enumeration as new type. Solution:

```
class proA
{
public:
  typedef enum
  {
    jnkA,
    jnkB,
    jnkC
  }  myEnum;
};
```